# git diff should also show filename

Tags: git

How do I get git-diff to show the filename in addition to the diff? I'm not asking to show just the filenames, I would like to see the diff *in addition to* the filenames. I am aware of tools out there like gitk and piping outputs to vimdiff, but I wanted to see if there was a way to make the diff itself show filenames.

Comment: But it does show it... At the very top of every file that has a diff.

Comment: Oh my goodness...my diff highlighting was set to the same color as the background...=[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is shown for each file on top of the changes, for example look at this picture and test.php file name : 
[image]

Comment: I realized that it was just a silly error on my part, but this is correct, and thus I will accept it. Cheers.